# How to exclude records with a Combined AND Condition. Individually the records can exist

Tags: amazon-redshift

How to put WHERE condition in Amazon Redshift  in which the Scenario is as below:

```
SELECT A.a,B.a 
FROM Table A
   LEFT JOIN B b
   ON A.x=B.x
WHERE NOT (A.y='ABC' AND B.y='DEF')
```

What i want to do is to fetch all the results except the ones where the combined condition `(A.y="ABC" AND B.y="DEF")` is not there.

there can be records with `A.y="ABC" and B.y="DEF"` individually but when the condition is met `(A.y="ABC" AND B.y="DEF")` then those records should not be fetched

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Its actually 'ABC'. Its Redshift but i believe most postgres queries run on redshift